# 'PHP' Здравствуйте, у меня после загрузки страницы добавляются новые записи в файл. Как очистить $_post после загрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, php, html, php7, php5

Помогите, пожалуйста, с кодом.
Мой код:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15MBDi-6nfM28rv9O9-ubtYRA67DN97kV/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UsuMbOVag0OA6YvZSD8XOzFd1EAdLWWM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Код вставляйте __сюда__ текстом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пропиши в конце скрипта:

```
header('Location: /index.php');
```

и удали инклуды. После обработки формы эта штука перенаправит на нужную страницу => очистит $_POST.

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\test.ru\www\safe\file.txt:12) , не работает

Comment: Каким редактором пользуешься? Открой скрипт в Notepad++, увидишь пустую строку в начале файла. Удалишь - всё заработает. Это известный косяк с этой функцией.

Comment: И зачем ты передаёшь текст в виде разметки? Если это целенаправленно, то вместо "class" используй атрибут "style="color: green". Хотя я не понимаю, зачем это нужно.